# UIActionsheet in the middle of the screen

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

I want to show a UIActionSheet in the middle of the screen.I tried with the following code

```
UIView *placeholderview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 310, 320, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:placeholderview];
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Open File",@"Save FIle",@"New File",@"Export Image",nil];
[actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 10) inView:placeholderview animated:YES];
[actionSheet release];
```

I get the result as desired but i can click only cancel button, and the half of export image button.I don't know where i am going wrong.Kindly please any body help me.What should i do to make it working.[image]

Comment: what is the exactly problem you are facing,plz elaborate your question is not understandable

Comment: is possibly only the part inside your placeholderview clickable? have you tried to expand it?

Comment: I dont think apple will be happy with this..:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIActionSheet` is designed to be presented from the bottom of the screen.

It provides methods for presenting from a toolbar or tab bar in cases where those UI elements may cause obstruction.

Why are you wanting to show the action sheet in the middle of the screen. I wouldn't recommend this because it looks wrong, and isn't the designed behaviour of the control.

The method you are currently using is for iPad - it shouldn't be used on iPhone, as it causes undefined behaviour (as you are experiencing).

Answer (score 3):

`UIActionSheet`'s [`showFromRect:inView:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006801-CH3-SW30) method is only supposed to be used on iPad. Its behavior on iPhone is undefined.